# Chroma key in aframe

Tags: video, aframe, chromakey

How to chroma key a video in aframe?
I want to have a video of a person looking like an hologram in aframe.

I've been looking into [this](https://github.com/nikolaiwarner/aframe-chromakey-material/blob/master/README.md) but can't make it work for some reason.
Does anyone has any idea of how to chroma key in aframe? (or another solution for what I want to accomplish is very welcome as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to chroma key with [this material](https://github.com/nikolaiwarner/aframe-chromakey-material/blob/master/README.md) one needs to use .mp4 format for the video. Previously I was using .mov and that's why I was just getting a black screen. Converted the video to .mp4 and it works.